# Main storyboard on Swift gives Github error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, github

We are coding for senior project. But when I pull project on Xcode, main.storyboard gives an error like in picture. I discarded all changes and cleaned my project, but it did not work. Half of project is on my friend computer, half of is on mine. How can I fix this GitHub error and how can we compound this parts ? Ps : I have backup of my project in another folder. 
[image: github error picture]

Comment: Don't attempt to merge storyboard versions. Keep either your or your friend's version if you are trying to merge two branches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storyboards are `.xml` files. The issue you have recently happened to me after I didn't properly resolve GitHub merge conflicts. When you don't edit the stuff in the <<<<< >>>>>> brackets properly, inside the file that has merge conflicts, you can generate the ID conflicts.

You either have to open the `xml` file of the storyboard with Xcode itself (or with a Texteditor like Sublime) and fix it manually (if you know what you are doing and where the duplicate elements are, as the file xml-structure is quite complex). The BEST way (especially since you have a backup) would be to go inside the project folder and replace the storyboard file with the old one. You will loose changes made since the backup, but if you commit frequently, it should not be too far behind.

EDIT: If the rest of the stuff you merged relies on a newer version of the storyboard (e.g. IBOutlets or IBActions), you will have to recreate those assets in the storyboard and re-connect them to your code.

Another route instead of replacing the storyboard file would be to do a git hard reset to your last commit before the merge and then attempt to merge again. At that point try to resolve the storyboard conflicts better, which may be very difficult. Don't worry, storyboard merge conflicts are a big pain to every developer. If nothing helps, resetting by replacing the file above should always work.

GENERAL RULE: Try to use multiple storyboards for your viewcontrollers. Group them into storyboards as you see fit. That way if one storyboard gets conflicted, it will easier to reset it and then manually adjust it to the latest state. It is also less likely to get merge conflicts in the first place because it's unlikely that two coders will work on the same storyboard file. Usually working on the same file is fine, when editing different lines but storyboards are different. As soon as you open them you get all sorts of `view misplaced` stuff and other things edited into the xml automatically. So if you open one and didn't actually change anything, reset the changes and don't commit it.

Comment: You don't even need an external editor for viewing the Storyboard file as an xml, you can do that directly in Xcode as well.